# Maven build skips clean and validate phases

Tags: java, maven

I am using IntelliJ IDE. My project is `maven project`. What is bothering me is that when for example choose "Install" phase from Maven Toolbar and click "Run Maven Build"[image],

the `clean` phase is not executed:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=A:\custom_software_projects\IdeaProjects\power_management "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=53577:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.3.2 install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building power_server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ power_server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ power_server ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ power_server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory A:\custom_software_projects\IdeaProjects\power_management\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ power_server ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ power_server ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ power_server ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) @ power_server ---
[INFO] Building jar: A:\custom_software_projects\IdeaProjects\power_management\target\power_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:unpack-dependencies (unpack-sigar) @ power_server ---
[INFO] log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 already exists in destination.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ power_server ---
[INFO] Installing A:\custom_software_projects\IdeaProjects\power_management\target\power_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\ggeorgiev\.m2\repository\Power_Management_Server\power_server\1.0-SNAPSHOT\power_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing A:\custom_software_projects\IdeaProjects\power_management\pom.xml to C:\Users\ggeorgiev\.m2\repository\Power_Management_Server\power_server\1.0-SNAPSHOT\power_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing A:\custom_software_projects\IdeaProjects\power_management\target\power_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar to C:\Users\ggeorgiev\.m2\repository\Power_Management_Server\power_server\1.0-SNAPSHOT\power_server-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.4:run (Copying jar-with-dependecnies and fixing LF in .sh scripts) @ power_server ---
project.artifactId
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [copy] Copying 1 file to A:\custom_programs\power_server
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.291 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-10T21:42:17+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, as you see the first step taken is `maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources`. From what I understood from [`maven` docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) is that when we specify a phase all previous phases are executed up to the chosen one. Per maven doc:

`This command executes each default life cycle phase in order (validate, compile, package, etc.), before executing install. You only need to call the last build phase to be executed, in this case, install`

Why is it skipping the `clean` and `validate` phases?

*Edit*:

I also have the `clean` phase in the `Run Configuration` section, but the result is the same:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I won't answer because I was unaware that maven should execute all previous phases before the chosen one. However, a workaround is to create a maven goal configuration and specify `clean validate install` as the goal.

Comment: @MarDev I have `clean` phase in `Run Configurations`. I'll update the question

Comment: `clean` might just be an odd case as I remember having to specify `clean install` when doing many tasks - let me check the docs

Comment: Indeed, the default lifecycle does not include `clean` in it - the `clean` lifecycle is a separate from the default one - check the docs you linked to

Comment: @ochi I see. You are right. But what about `validate`? Seems it is part of the lifecycle but still not executed?

Comment: @CuriousGuy What I am saying is edit your power_server configuration. In the edit scene, next to command line, it will say clean. Append validate and install. For example, my configuration for my project says `clean install exec:java -e`. You can specify multiple goals. After doing so, once you run power clean, it will execute all those goals. Now, to run your project, instead of clicking clean under lifecycle goals, you would click power_server under run configurations.

Comment: Since you are packaging a `.jar` file, the default lifecycle does not include validate in its listing of phases to execute (see the bottom of the docs in the *Default Lifecycle Bindings* Reference listing

Comment: The `validate` phase is being executed but you can't see it cause no plugin is bound to it...The `clean` is not a life cycle phase. `clean` is part of the life cycle `clean` which contains `pre-clean`, `clean` and `post-clean`(It's a little bit confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default lifecycle does not include `clean` in it.  Check the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Quote:

> For example, the default lifecycle comprises of the following phases
>   (for a complete list of the lifecycle phases, refer to the Lifecycle
>   Reference):
>
> - validate - validate the project is correct and all necessary
>     information is available
> - compile - compile the source code of the
>     project
> - test - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit
>     testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged
>     or deployed
> - package - take the compiled code and package it in its
>     distributable format, such as a JAR.
> - verify - run any checks on
>     results of integration tests to ensure quality criteria are met
> - install - install the package into the local repository, for use as a
>     dependency in other projects locally
> - deploy - done in the build
>     environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for
>     sharing with other developers and projects.

Also, the `validate` phase is not associated with the default lifecycle of packaging `.jar` files.

Check the *Default Lifecycle Bindings* for JAR files at the bottom of the docs

Comment: See @Oleg's answer. Difference between `default-lifecycle` and `clean` life cycle and `site` life cycle..

Comment: @khmarbaise I did, I agree is a better answer.. I upvoted it accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Maven has 3 different builtin [lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics)

> There are three built-in build lifecycles: **default**, **clean** and **site**.

`install` is part of the default lifecycle and there is no reason for `clean` to execute when you do `install`.

As to `validate` it has no built in binding as you can see [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) which means that it's not going to [execute](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#A_Build_Phase_is_Made_Up_of_Plugin_Goals):

> Furthermore, a build phase can also have zero or more goals bound to it. If a build phase has no goals bound to it, that build phase will not execute.